# Doctrine 2 need Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am trying to make Doctrine 2 work. But on the [documentation page about the CLI tool](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/tools.html), it's including something in Symfony...

```
$helperSet = new \Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\HelperSet(array(
    'db' => new \Doctrine\DBAL\Tools\Console\Helper\ConnectionHelper($em->getConnection()),
    'em' => new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\Helper\EntityManagerHelper($em)
));
```

What * * is that ? Why do you need Symfony to make Doctrine work ?

It seems completely odd to me, but I can't make my mind to download Symfony just for the missing class... Can you help me ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The doctrine console stuff uses some Symfony Components (which are [standalone libraries](http://components.symfony-project.org/), packaged separately from the full framework).

So it's nothing strange -- the doctrine team just avoided reinventing a perfectly good wheel.

Comment: Ok if it comes packaged with it, I agree with the "the doctrine team just avoided reinventing a perfectly good wheel.". Apparently I downloaded a version that didn't contain those components, I'll try again. Thanks.

Comment: I'm 99% sure the tarball distributions include everything.  I've had issues pulling doctrine into projects via git, but YMMV.

Answer (score 3):

Installing the DoctrineSymfonyConsole will probably fix it:

```
pear install doctrine/DoctrineSymfonyConsole
```

If you installed Doctrine from pear, you probably had errors that were handled gracefully.  try installing all dependencies:

```
pear install -af doctrine/DoctrineORM
```

Make sure there are no problems.  If there are missing packages, it should warn you and you'll want to install those.  I've had issues in the past where -a (all dependencies) didn't error if there was a problem installing a dependency, and the install halted even though it reported success.

http://pear.doctrine-project.org/

Comment: I like to [install Doctrine from GitHub](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/introduction.html#github)

Comment: It really just comes down to preference (like using YUM vs compiling sources), but I consider PEAR to be more universal. The other added benefit is not having to adjust the include_path for a default install.

Either way, installing just the doctrine/DoctrineSymfonyConsole will solve the problem.  You can either use the PEAR command from my answer above, or download them from the link @timdev listed in his answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you download the latest Doctrine tar.gz file, the Symfony Console comes prepackaged with it. No need to do a separate download. You'll find a folder named Symfony in the Doctrine folder. It has the Console and Yaml components.

Comment: Ok I'll try to download again.